# Prove that there exists an isometry $S \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $T = \sqrt{TT^*}S$.

Tags: linear-algebra, isometry

This the third exercise in section 7.D from Axler's book (Linear Algebra Done Right).

> Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Prove that there exists an isometry $S \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ such that
>
> $$T = \sqrt{TT^*}S.$$

$V$ is a finite-dimension inner product space.

I'm don't have any ideas on how to begin this.
Any tips?

Comment: For any $T$ ?....

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry. I edited the question.

Comment: It reminds me of "polar decomposition".

Comment: I know, but I can't relate this to the proof Axler gives of the polar decomposition.

Comment: A positive definite matrix can always be written as the square of another positive definite matrix (whose eigenvalues are the square roots of the initial one) to which you apply a Cholesky factorization.

Comment: It seems to be called 'left polar decomposition'.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it was considerably easier than I thought.

By the Polar Decomposition, there exists an isometry $S \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $T^* = S\sqrt{TT^*}$.
Taking the adjoint of each side, we get

$$
T = (S\sqrt{TT^*})^* = (\sqrt{TT^*})^*S^* = \sqrt{TT^*}S^*,
$$

where the last equality follows because $\sqrt{TT^*}$ is self-adjoint.
This yields the desired result, because $S^*$ is also an isometry.